# Signal not delivered for a very long time (about 20 seconds)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, signals

A signal that a process has sent to itself from within a signal handler could not get delivered for about 20 seconds and then it was delivered.

What could be the probable causes?

I would like to know the probable reasons in general.

The actual Code I am looking at is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/libbacktrace/BacktraceCurrent.cpp#142)

Comment: Have you tried to investigate using `strace`? I guess the program hangs for 20 seconds in a kernel call.

Comment: @hek2mgl  Well it does not happen everytime. So I cannot use strace. I have just updated the source code link. pls let me know your thoughts

Comment: @mk.. what's "THREAD_SIGNAL"?

Comment: If you are coding for Linux (specifically), you might be interested in using [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Its sig 33. Used for generating backtrace.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, you're calling a function from within a signal handler that you mustn't call from within that signal handler.

See `man 7 signal` for details:

> **Async-signal-safe functions**
>
> A  signal  handler function must be very careful, since processing elsewhere may be interrupted at some arbitrary point in the
>   execution of the program.  POSIX has the
>          concept of "safe function".  If a signal interrupts the execution of an unsafe function, and handler calls an unsafe function,
>   then the  behavior  of  the  program  is
>          undefined.

Comment: I feel both the functions are safe functions. I have updated the source code link. Pls have a look if possible.

Comment: This might not be the reason in *this* particular case, but the OP asked for general advices, and this is a good advice in general. Plus one!

Comment: @mk: Read *carefully* [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). Your `SignalHandler` is indirectly calling `pthread_mutex_lock`  which is *not* in the list of async-signal-safe functions.

Comment: "POSIX.1-2004 (also known as POSIX.1-2001 Technical Corrigendum 2) requires an implementation to guarantee that the following functions can be safely called inside a signal handler:" I kind of dont understand this statement. "guarantee" - who should guarantee? Does it means that the listed functions are safe or unsafe? Sorry to bother you.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The exact issue is https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=162896&can=1&q=libbacktrace&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars#makechanges

Comment: @mk: it means that all the functions not listed are unsafe, ans since `pthread_mutex_lock` is not listed, you are not allowed to call it, even indirectly, inside a signal handler.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thank you. But, According to what i understand, there will be a problem if the process that is blocked is inside pthread_mutex_lock() and signal handler calls it as well. But I dont see it here. The signal handler is giving the signal to itself, hence the issue in this case could be different. No? Am I getting it still wrong.

Comment: No, the issue *may* appear if the signal handler is using some unauthorized functions, e.g. `pthread_mutex_lock`; the point is that stricto sensu a signal handler can use (even indirectly) only a very restricted set of functions and *everything else is forbidden*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79729/discussion-between-mk-and-basile-starynkevitch).